# Adding alias name is giving error in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, alias

I want to give alias name to my column name in a `stored procedure` But its not coming as I want. Below is the code which I tried

```
STREX:='SELECT DISTINCT AM.APP_MST_ID, NVL(AM.APPLICATIONNAME,''-'') as ''APPLICATION NAME'', NVL(AD.URLPATH,''-'')URL, NVL(AM.PROJECTNO,''-'')PROJECTNO, NVL(AM.VSS_FOLDER_LOC,''-'')VSSFOLDERLOC,
         NVL(AU.NAME, ''-'')SPOCUSER, NVL(AUR.NAME,''-'')REQUESTEDBY, NVL(AUD.NAME,''-'')DELIVERYMANAGER             
           FROM APPLICATION_MASTER AM 
                INNER JOIN APPLICATION_DETAILS AD
                   ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AD.APP_MST_ID 
                INNER JOIN APPUSER_UMS AU
                   ON AM.APP_MST_ID = AU.APP_USERID    
                   INNER JOIN APPUSER_UMS AUR
                 ON AUR.APP_USERID = AM.REQUESTED_BY_APPUSRID  
                 INNER JOIN  APPUSER_UMS AUD
                      ON AUD.APP_USERID = AM.DELIVERY_MANAGER_APPUSRID  
                       WHERE UPPER(AM.'|| P_PARAM_TYPE || ') ' || P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM';
         /* WHERE AM.'|| UPPER(P_PARAM_TYPE) ||' '|| P_OPERATOR  || ' :PARAM'; */

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STREX '|| STREX);
 OPEN P_RETURN FOR STREX USING VAL;
```

> I want to show as Application Name for first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
...SELECT DISTINCT AM.APP_MST_ID, NVL(AM.APPLICATIONNAME,''-'') as "Application Name"...
```

Double quotes (") are used to specify identifier names, single quotes (') are used to delimit character strings in data.

Comment: yes, thanks it is working.. Earlier I tried with single `'` but it didnt worked. I was confused whether it will create so much conflict between using single and double quote